# Distinguish between two gtktreeviews

Tags: c, gtk

I need to know which gtktreeview was passed to a function from the handler (An identical function used for several button/treeview combinations so this is much more efficient than making a ton of different functions)

The problem is that once the function gets the treeview and has to work with it there doesn't seem to be a way to identify it (Even based on something as simple as the amount of columns)

```
void
add_button_clicked(GtkTreeView * treeview,GtkButton * widget){
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkListStore * store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview));
    gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);

    if(items)
        gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                            ITEM_COL_ENABLED, 1,
                            -1);
    else if(locations)
        gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                            LOCATION_COL_NAME, "Broken Shores",
                            LOCATION_COL_ENABLED, 1,
                            -1);
}
```

How can I distinguish between the two?

Comment: Cant you give `user_data` as a custom parameter when you connect a callback function to the event? Can you show how you *connect* the callback to the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach arbitrary data to any GObject; this is often overlooked, but it's perfect for identifying the tree views in your case. When creating the treeview, do:

```
g_object_set_data(treeview, "id", GINT_TO_POINTER(1));
```

Then in your callback:

```
if(GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_object_get_data(treeview, "id")) == 1) {
    /* This is tree view #1 */
}
```

Comment: I actually had to use that to identify the column in the model that I wanted to edit, good answer!